# Java generic method Cannot resolve method 'getX()' in 'T'

Tags: java

Say I have a couple of Objects (=classes) which each has a method `getX()`:

```java
public class A{
   /* some code */
   public float getX(){}
}
public class B{
   /* some code */
   public float getX(){}
}
```

Now I want to write a generic static method as the following:

```java
public static <T> boolean isOverlaps(T obj) {
   if (obj == null || (!obj.getClass().isInstance(A.class) && !obj.getClass().isInstance(B.class)))
       return false;
   return obj.getX() >= 0 && /*some logic*/; // here it falls
}
```

IDE says:

> Cannot resolve method 'getX()' in 'T'

How can I resolve the method properly without casting (since it is a generic method)? Is it even possible?

Comment: Try defining a common interface between A and B with the method getX. Then in <T> definition of your static fuction you need to add <T extends YOUR_INTERFACE>. Then it should work

Comment: You could go for interface and change T to the interface. You will do not need any class check also

Comment: Ok thanks I will do it

Comment: Java doesn't have this kind of pattern matching yet. You will need a common type between A and B as the other comments suggest

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks! Admins, you may lock the question if needed (I have no idea how to do it myself)

Comment: You'll be able to delete it if you wish

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need an interface to let Java know that `T` has the desired function:

```
public interface I {
   float getX();
}

public class A implements I {
   /* some code */
   public float getX(){
       return 1.0f;
   }
}
public class B implements I {
   /* some code */
   public float getX(){
       return 2.0f;
   }
}

public static <T extends I> boolean isOverlaps(T obj) {
   return obj.getX() >= 0 && /*some logic*/;
}
```

Or, a bit simpler without the unnecessary type variable:

```
public static boolean isOverlaps(I obj) {
   return obj.getX() >= 0 && /*some logic*/;
}
```

Comment: `isOverlaps` doesn't need a type variable. Just declare it as `isOverlaps(I obj)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using an interface is the preferred way to solve this, but the statement "you *need* an interface" is incorrect.

You can achieve this without an interface too. In some situations (i.e. where you can't modify A or B), this may be the best you can do.

```
public static boolean isOverlaps(Object obj) {     
    float x = -1;
    if (obj instanceof A) {
        x = ((A) obj).getX();
    }
    else if (obj instanceof B) {
        x = ((B) obj).getX();
    }
         
    return x >= 0 && /*some logic*/;
}
```

Comment: Yeah well, this way I write the same line twice (the same line twice), so it stops "being generic" in any way :)

Comment: Since Java 14 you can directly bind it to variable of the proper type `if (obj instanceof A a) { x = a.getX();}`

Comment: @Niles of course you can use reflection too with `float x = (float) obj.getClass().getMethod("getX").invoke(obj);` though interfaces are way better

Comment: @Niles Yours is not "generic in any way" either, because you manually checked for A and B.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <T> boolean isOverlaps(T obj) {
```

This isn't *really* a generic method. OK, it is a generic method, because it has a type variable; it's just not a *usefully* generic method. You can pass anything to it: it's essentially equivalent to:

```
public static boolean isOverlaps(Object obj) {
```

That is, you can't access anything inside that method which isn't a method on `Object`.

If you want to use this, and you can't use the common interface approach, you could do an `instanceof` chain:

```
public static boolean isOverlaps(Object obj) {
  if (obj instanceof A) {
    return /* logic */;
  } else if (obj instanceof B) {
    // Do something.
    return /* logic */;
  }
  return false;
}
```

The problem with this is that you're losing the compile-time safety of not being allowed to pass things other than `A`s and `B`s to it (e.g. you could call `isOverlaps("Hello world!")`, which is presumably nonsensical).

It's actually better to define two overloads:

```
public static boolean isOverlaps(A obj) { return /* logic */; }

public static boolean isOverlaps(B obj) { return /* logic */; }
```

because now trying to pass in anything other than an `A` or a `B` results in a compile-time error; but it's a compile-time error at the call site, not in these methods.

If `/* logic */` depends on some property which can be derived from `A` and `B`, e.g. a getter, you can consolidate the repeated logic into a helper:

```
public static boolean isOverlaps(A obj) { return helper(obj.getX()); }

public static boolean isOverlaps(B obj) { return helper(obj.getX()); }

private static boolean helper(SomeType value) {
  return /* logic */
}
```